# Should a webassembly runtime create an AST of the instructions?

Tags: java, virtual-machine, interpreter, webassembly

I am building a web assembly interpreter in Java and am now thinking about how to best model the instructions. This is my first try at building a compiler/runtime.

Currently, I've modelled a [function](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/modules.html#functions) as a class with the type, a list of locals and the code as a `byte[]` of instructions, as retrieved from the binary storage format.

In the execution, I'm just iterating over each byte of the instructions (which I'm getting from a ByteBuffer, which wraps the `byte[]`) and switching based on the value, like this:

```java
    public void execute() {
        int opCode = code.get();

        // 0x0b is the end of the current block
        while (opCode != 0x0b) {
            if (opCode == 0x20) {
                localGet();
            } else if (opCode == 0x7c) {
                i64add();
            } else if (opCode == 0x6a) {
                i32add();
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Opcode %d not yet supported", opCode));
            }

            opCode = code.get();
        }
    }
```

Is this a "good" approach? I can also imagine of parsing each instruction and creating individual classes for each instruction (e.g. `LocalGet`) during module loading and then creating a AST. But I wonder if this is really necessary here, because the instructions seem to be just a linear list following one another (with the exception of the blocks, where I think I have to create a secondary stack to keep track of the nested level).

Furthermore, the webassembly reference lists the exact steps for each instruction according to the main stack, so I'm not sure what an AST would bring here (as I'm not resolving starting from the terminal nodes, but instead working linearly through the instructions).

Comment: The question is, without intermediate representation how are you going to tackle control flow? (if, loops, switch etc.) 

You probably can store module position, jump back in the source and decode module over and over on each loop iteration, but that will be rather inefficient compared to pre-parsed AST.

I recommend playing with those different approaches once you get to implementing those instructions and see which one feels harder to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, my approach ended up like this:

- Creating an `Instruction` interface

  ```java
  public interface Instruction {
    void execute(Store store, WasmStack stack);
  }
  ```
- Creating classes for each instruction which hold the immediate value as a field (e.g. a `LocalGet` instruction) and contain the actual logic from [the webassembly documentation](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/instructions.html).
- Parsing the bytecode of the module before instantiation and appending each parsed Instruction to a `List<Instruction>`.
- During runtime, just executing each instruction sequentially (like a function pointer) by retrieving the current instruction from the list and then executing the method.

The most difficult problem was the branching structure, specifically the `block` instruction, which needs to know the position of the end of the block. During parsing, I've therefore created a simple stack `Deque<Instruction>` where I am pushing each control instruction (that is, each instruction which is terminated by an `end`) and when an `end` is encountered, I modify the original control instruction to set the position of the `end` (because it's at the top of the stack but also already added to the list of instructions).

During runtime, the `end` instruction then changes the function pointer (which is just a simple `for (int i = 0; i < instructions.size(); i++)` by changing the `i` from inside the `execute` method. This was actually a easy way to implement control flow, because it's possible to skip instructions or go back.